# How to change a value in an array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [error] = Array
        (
            [0] = Password field is required.
            [1] = Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="/user/password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>
        )

)
```

In the above array I need to add an class in the link. My expected output should be like:

```
Array
(
    [error] = Array
        (
            [0] = Password field is required.
            [1] = Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="/user/password" class="popups">Have you forgotten your password?</a>
        )

)
```

How do I change the array value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like str_replace on it before printing the link to the page.

Answer (score 0):

`$array['error'][1] = ...`, but from the sound of it, I think you might want to change the value wherever it was set originally. In that case, just search your code for `Sorry, unrecognized username or password.` or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
$somearray['somekey'] = 'newvalue';
$somearray['somekey']['otherkey'] = 'othernewvalue';
```

... basic PHP...